# How to paginate custom query result in cakephp 4

Tags: cakephp, pagination, cakephp-4.x

I am learning **CakePHP 4**, had been using CakePHP 2, and I'm having trouble paginating a custom query. I get everything correctly with the following code:

```
$this->paginate = [ 'contain' => ['AssociatedTable1', 'AssociatedTable2','AssociatedTable3'] ];
$result = $this->paginate($this->PrimaryTable);
$this->set(compact('result '));
```

But when I add conditions like below I get a database error. Where or how do I put conditions?

```
$this->paginate = [ 'contain' => ['AssociatedTable1', 'AssociatedTable2','AssociatedTable3'],
    'conditions' => ['AssociatedTable2.column3' => 15]
];
$result = $this->paginate($this->PrimaryTable);
$this->set(compact('result '));
'''
```

Comment: Best way I know to paginate a custom query is to make yourself a Query object that does what you want, and then pass that to `$this->paginate` instead of the table object.

Comment: Make the query outside the pagination and then pass your result into the paginate method $result = $this->PrimaryTable->find('all')->contain([''AssociatedTable1''])'->where(['AssociatedTable2.column3' => 1]); $result = $this->paginate($result);